# como filtrar um objeto json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filtro, filter

Eu tenho o seguinte objeto json:

```
var json = {
    "acao": "listaHoteis",
    "hoteisPesquisa": [
        {
            "home_id": "1",
            "nome": "Itamarati"
            "preco": "925"
        }, {
            "home_id": "2",
            "nome": "copacabana"
            "preco": "102.1"
        }, {
            "home_id": "3",
            "nome": "Itamarati"
            "preco": "215"
        },{
            "home_id": "4",
            "nome": "Litoral Htel"
            "preco": "1001"
        }
    ]
};
```

Como faço para filtrar esse objeto para que so mostre os hoteis onde o preço for maior quem 100 e menor que 900?

```
var json = {
    "acao": "listaHoteis",
    "hoteisPesquisa": [
        {
            "home_id": "2",
            "nome": "copacabana"
            "preco": "102.1"
        }, {
            "home_id": "3",
            "nome": "Itamarati"
            "preco": "215"
        }
    ]
};
```

Existe alguma maneira eu posso filtrar o objeto e manter todas as propriedades? Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo teu JSON vejo que tens os preços em *String*. tens de converter em número e depois usar `.filter()` para remover os que não queres.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
var json = {
  "acao": "listaHoteis",
  "hoteisPesquisa": [{
    "home_id": "1",
    "nome": "Itamarati",
    "preco": "925"
  }, {
    "home_id": "2",
    "nome": "copacabana",
    "preco": "102.1"
  }, {
    "home_id": "3",
    "nome": "Itamarati",
    "preco": "215"
  }, {
    "home_id": "4",
    "nome": "Litoral Hotel",
    "preco": "1001"
  }]
};

var filtrados = json.hoteisPesquisa.filter(function(hotel) {
  var preco = Number(hotel.preco);
  return preco > 100 && preco < 900;
});

console.log(filtrados);
```

Comment: Obrigado funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Como faço para filtrar do mesmo jeito do primeiro esse json:

```
var json = {
   "tpAmbiente":null,
   "hotelPesquisa":[
      {
         "dtEntrada":"20170510",
         "dtSaida":"20170511",
         "hotel":{
            "id":94,
            "nome":"Itamarati"
         },
         "quarto":[
            {
               "quartoUh":[
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 1,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 2,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dtEntrada":"20170510",
         "dtSaida":"20170511",
         "hotel":{
            "id":95,
            "nome":"copacabana"
         },
         "quarto":[
            {
               "quartoUh":[
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 1,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":102.1,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 2,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":102.1,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dtEntrada":"20170510",
         "dtSaida":"20170511",
         "hotel":{
            "id":96,
            "nome":"Itamarati"
         },
         "quarto":[
            {
               "quartoUh":[
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 1,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 2,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dtEntrada":"20170510",
         "dtSaida":"20170511",
         "hotel":{
            "id":96,
            "nome":"Litoral Hotel"
         },
         "quarto":[
            {
               "quartoUh":[
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 1,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":1001.00,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 2,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":1001.00,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};
```

Nesse o preço fica em:

```
hotelPesquisa[].quarto[].quartoUh[].tarifa.vlDiariaTotal
```

tem como filtrar do mesmo jeito? maior que 100 e menor que 900?